# how to refresh ssrs report inside an mvc4 razor application without refresh whole page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, reporting-services

I have a ssrs  report in MVC 4 razor where I am generating report on search parameter clicked. First time report generated without any issue but when I clicked ssrs report next page pagination done but my search parameter blank due to whole page refresh . I don't want to refresh whole page ssrs pagination time .I want to only refresh ssrs portion.

View page (index.html). Following is my snapshot:

[image: Snapshot]

```
ssrs report code:

<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Emenox.Models.Reports.AptekaReportModel>" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<script runat="server">

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Required for report events to be handled properly.



        Context.Handler = Page;


    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {

            ServerReport report = ReportViewer1.ServerReport;
            ReportParameter[] rptParameters = new ReportParameter[14];

            rptParameters[0] = new ReportParameter("CompanyId", Model.CompanyId.HasValue ? Model.CompanyId.Value.ToString() : "0", false);
            rptParameters[1] = new ReportParameter("YearId", Model.YearId.HasValue ? Model.YearId.Value.ToString() : "0", false);
            rptParameters[2] = new ReportParameter("MonthId", Model.MonthId.HasValue ? Model.MonthId.Value.ToString() : "0", false);
            rptParameters[3] = new ReportParameter("RegionId", Model.RegionId.HasValue ? Model.RegionId.Value.ToString() : "0", false);
            rptParameters[4] = new ReportParameter("RepresentativeId", Model.RepresentativeId.HasValue ? Model.RepresentativeId.Value.ToString() : "0", false);
            rptParameters[5] = new ReportParameter("ProductId", Model.ProductId.HasValue ? Model.ProductId.Value.ToString() : "0", false);
            rptParameters[6] = new ReportParameter("CompanyName", Model.CompanyName, false);
            rptParameters[7] = new ReportParameter("YearName", Model.YearName, false);
            rptParameters[8] = new ReportParameter("MonthName", Model.MonthName, false);
            rptParameters[9] = new ReportParameter("RegionName", Model.RegionName, false);
            rptParameters[10] = new ReportParameter("RepresentativeName", Model.RepresentativeName, false);
            rptParameters[11] = new ReportParameter("ProductName", Model.ProductName, false);
            rptParameters[12] = new ReportParameter("PartyName", Model.PartyName, false);
            rptParameters[13] = new ReportParameter("UserId", Model.UserId.HasValue ? Model.UserId.Value.ToString() : "0", false);
            // rptParameters[3] = new ReportParameter("ProductName",Model.ProductName, false);


            report.ReportServerCredentials = new MyReportServerCredentials();
            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
            try
            {
                ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new System.Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServerUrl"].ToString());
                ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportPath"].ToString() + "/AptekaReport.rdl";
                ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(rptParameters);
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
            }
            catch { };
        }

    }

    [Serializable]
    protected class MyReportServerCredentials : IReportServerCredentials
    {

        public MyReportServerCredentials()
        {
        }

        public System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
        {
            get
            {
                return null;  // Use default identity.
            }
        }

        public System.Net.ICredentials NetworkCredentials
        {
            get
            {
                return new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NetworkUserName"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NetworkPassword"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NetworkDoamin"].ToString());
            }
        }

        public bool GetFormsCredentials(out System.Net.Cookie authCookie,
                out string user, out string password, out string authority)
        {
            authCookie = null;
            user = password = authority = null;
            return false;  // Not use forms credentials to authenticate.
        }
    }

</script>

<form id="Form1" runat="server">

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false" >

    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" ZoomMode="PageWidth" SizeToReportContent="True"
        runat="server" AsyncRendering="false" ShowFindControls="true" 
        ProcessingMode="Remote" ShowParameterPrompts="False" Width="100%">
        <ServerReport DisplayName="Media Expenses Report" />
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>


</form>

controller code :
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            AptekaReportModel model = new AptekaReportModel();
            if (Session["UserId"] != null && Session["RoleName"].ToString() != null)
            {
                model.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);
                model.RoleName = Session["RoleName"].ToString();
                model.CompanyList = CommonFunctions.GetCompanyListByUserId(model.UserId.Value, model.RoleName);                
                model.ProductList = CommonFunctions.GetProductsWithSKU();
                //model.ProductList = CommonFunctions.GetProductsByUserId(Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]), Session["RoleName"].ToString());
                model.RepresentativeList = CommonFunctions.GetRepresentativeByUserId(Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]), Session["RoleName"].ToString());
                model.YearList = CommonFunctions.GetYear();
                model.MonthList = CommonFunctions.GetMonth();

                model.RepresentativeTypeList = CommonFunctions.GetRepresentativeTypeList();
            }
            return View(model);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Search
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="model"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>


 public ActionResult Search(AptekaReportModel model)
        {
           // AptekaReportModel model = new AptekaReportModel();

        model.IsSearch = true;
        if (Session["UserId"] != null && Session["RoleName"].ToString() != null)
        {
            model.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);
            model.RoleName = Session["RoleName"].ToString();
            model.CompanyList = CommonFunctions.GetCompanyListByUserId(model.UserId.Value, model.RoleName);

            //model.ProductList = CommonFunctions.GetProductsByUserId(Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]), Session["RoleName"].ToString());
            //   model.RepresentativeTypeList = CommonFunctions.GetRepresentativeTypeList();
            // model.RepresentativeList = CommonFunctions.GetRepresentativeByUserId(Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]), Session["RoleName"].ToString());                
        }
            model.YearList = CommonFunctions.GetYear();
            model.MonthList = CommonFunctions.GetMonth();
            model.ProductList = CommonFunctions.GetProductsWithSKU();

           // model.ActionStatus = true;

      //  if (Session["ProductList"] != null)
        //{
        //    model.ProductList = Session["ProductList"] as List<SelectListItem>;
        //}
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (model.CompanyId != null)
                model.CompanyName = CommonFunctions.GetCompanies().Where(x => x.Value == Convert.ToString(model.CompanyId)).SingleOrDefault().Text;
            if (model.YearId != null)
                model.YearName = CommonFunctions.GetYear().Where(x => x.Value == Convert.ToString(model.YearId)).SingleOrDefault().Text;
            if (model.MonthId != null)
                model.MonthName = CommonFunctions.GetMonth().Where(x => x.Value == Convert.ToString(model.MonthId)).SingleOrDefault().Text;
            //if (model.RegionId != null)
            //    model.RegionName = CommonFunctions.GetRegionList().Where(x => x.Value == Convert.ToString(model.RegionId)).FirstOrDefault().Text;
            if (model.RepresentativeId != null)
                model.RepresentativeName = CommonFunctions.GetMRs().Where(x => x.Value == Convert.ToString(model.RepresentativeId)).SingleOrDefault().Text;
            if (model.ProductId != null)
                     model.ProductName =  CommonFunctions.GetProductsWithSKU().Where(x => x.Value == Convert.ToString(model.ProductId)).SingleOrDefault().Text;
        }
        else
        {
           model.IsSearch = true;
        }
        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

Comment: This link will help you http://www.codemag.com/article/1009061

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div id="x">

   </div>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#x").load("/controller/action");
});
 </script>
```

Place the div in the view where you want to view the report.

Comment: hii sarath my issue is when i clicked on ssrs next page my select search parameter wold be bleank in this case . and pagination process done.

Answer (score 0):

Place the report inside an iframe. This will separate your view with the report. So clicking on pagination buttons of the report will not effect the search parameters present in your view.

Comment: hey Alorika can u send me some code refrence bcause i think i frame does not support in mvc4 razor

Comment: Go through this link: http://dotnetspeak.com/2012/02/using-ssrs-in-asp-net-mvc-application . It explains the process step by step. For a general idea, create an iframe where you want to show the report and provide the path of the aspx page (where the reportviewer is present) into the source of the iframe. This will generate the report inside the iframe.